# What may people do for gods?

Tags: humans, gods

Belief is one-sided affair. People believe and gods may decide if request will be fulfilled or not.

But what if people and gods could regularly cooperate? What if gods would ask people for help?

---

**Example:**
The Visitor gave Meadowers (those, who were known as Arch-trees and Arch-animals) all his knowledge and so they did not needed to ask him for help, at least for very long time.

When he died, civil war (later known as War for The Visitor's legacy) took place in the Meadows - and one of its results was that Arbich asked The Visitor for taking leadership of all Meadowers. The Visitor accepted - and became *wedding officer* and *high counsellor*. So, Meadowers could ask him for judging their quarrels.

But under one condition - they will do what he ask them for. Meadowers accepted The Visitor's condition - and so they are ready to do what he ask them for - and he fulfilled role of judge in some cases (... later Meadowers became solve their quarrels without help of The Visitor, because they found it easier and faster - as he wanted).

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how powerful the god is?  Or what makes for a good story (e.g. Noah had to do the work, rather than just being magically saved; Moses had to do the work with יהוה‎‎ actually making it harder, just because). So this is POB.

Comment: I'm not sure I see cooperation in your example.

Comment: Is your question: "what might villagers be able to do for a God that the God can't or would prefer not to do?"  Everything that I can think of would be opinion but traditional fantasy and SF tropes has a list that we could probably develop.

Answer (score 2):

Gods commonly require worship and sacrifices from their followers, as well as insisting that they follow certain rules, such as don't eat meat on Fridays, pray *n* times per day, don't work on certain days of the week, etc.

Otherwise, you can always find inspiration in the various mythologies, for gods like ordering mortals to do various tasks. For example:

- Hera, Athena and Aphrodite famously asked the mortal man [Paris to arbitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgement_of_Paris) their conflict about which of them [deserved the apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_of_Discord) inscribed *"to the most beatiful"*; each of them attempted to bribe him...
- [Themis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Themis) ordered [Deucalion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deucalion) and his wife Pyrrha to "throw the bones of their mother behind their shoulders" (the mother being [Gaia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_(mythology)) and her bones being rocks) in order to repopulate the earth after the flood.
- The God of Moses asked him to [make a box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_of_the_Covenant) with the intent that it be lost and that some three and a half thousand years later Harrison Ford will play Indiana Jones in [a movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raiders_of_the_Lost_Ark) about the search for that box.
- The same God frequently ordered various people (such as [Elijah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah) or [Samuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel)) to go to specified places and deliver certain messages, or to perform certain actions.

Gods also commonly require hospitality whenever they take a fancy to visit the world of the mortals. For example, Zeus required hospitality from [Lycaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycaon_(Arcadia)) (who tried to test the supreme god's omniscience by serving him the roasted flesh of Lycaon's own son Nyctimus as Wikipedia puts it) and from [Philemon and Baucis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baucis_and_Philemon).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of what a god might ask, first you must ask (and this will depend on you because it is you who has created this world and this god):

**What does your god want?**

The answer to that is going to depend on the kind of god this is, where your god's interests lie (woods god might like trees being planted or somesuch), how powerful your god is, and if they require worship like we require sustenance.

Gods come in a lot of different flavors and power levels, but even the supposedly all-powerful and all-knowing Abrahamic god asked for stuff from his followers--stuff like "don't eat that!" and "build a big boat and put a zoo on it" and "sacrifice your son to me! jK LOL! Just wanted to make sure you'd do anything I asked!"